# MCAR Little's test in Python

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, missing-data, imputation, hypothesis-test

How can I execute Little's Test, to find MCAR in Python? I have looked at the R package for the same test, but I want to do it in Python. Is there an alternate approach to test MCAR?

Comment: What about `impyute` library? Little’s MCAR Test (WIP) is in its feature list.

Comment: @Istrel impyute library does not explain how to do it (as far as I have seen), can you elaborate steps or give link for proper documentation.

Comment: The impyute library has a ticket to implement Little's MCAR Test, but it's not in progress: https://github.com/eltonlaw/impyute/issues/71

Answer (score 3):

You can use rpy2 to get the mcar test from R. Note that using rpy2 requires some R coding.

*Set up rpy2 in Google Colab*

```
# rpy2 libraries
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects import globalenv
```

```
# Import R's base package
base = importr("base")

# Import R's utility packages
utils = importr("utils")

# Select mirror 
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)

# For automatic translation of Pandas objects to R
pandas2ri.activate()

# Enable R magic
%load_ext rpy2.ipython

# Make your Pandas dataframe accessible to R
globalenv["r_df"] = df
```

You can now get R functionality within your Python environment by using R magics. Use `%R` for a single line of R code and `%%R` when the whole cell should be interpreted as R code.

To install an R package use:
`utils.install_packages("package_name")`

You may also need to load it before it can be used:
`%R library(package_name)`

For the Little's MCAR test, we should install the `naniar` package. Its installation is slightly more complicated as we also need to install `remotes` to download it from github, but for other packages the general procedure should be enough.

```
utils.install_packages("remotes")
%R remotes::install_github("njtierney/naniar")
```

Load `naniar` package:

```
%R library(naniar)
```

Pass your `r_df` to the `mcar_test` function:

```
# mcar_test on whole df
%R mcar_test(r_df)
```

If an error occurs, try including only the columns with missing data:

```
%%R
# mcar_test on columns with missing data
r_dfMissing <- r_df[c("col1", "col2", "col3")]
mcar_test(r_dfMissing)
```

Comment: Nice. Can you put a few words on why you would  include only variables with missing data? I thought the idea was to assess differences in variables grouped by missing/non-missing, which I cannot imagine will work if we drop cols without missing.

Comment: That's a good question. The only reason I suggested including variables with missing data  is because the mcar_test() function raises an error. I am not sure if this happens in every situation or just with the data I tried it with.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use this function to do a Little's MCAR test, instead of using R code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import chi2

def little_mcar_test(data, alpha=0.05):
    """
    Performs Little's MCAR (Missing Completely At Random) test on a dataset with missing values.
    
    Parameters:
    data (DataFrame): A pandas DataFrame with n observations and p variables, where some values are missing.
    alpha (float): The significance level for the hypothesis test (default is 0.05).
    
    Returns:
    A tuple containing:
    - A matrix of missing values that represents the pattern of missingness in the dataset.
    - A p-value representing the significance of the MCAR test.
    """
    
    # Calculate the proportion of missing values in each variable
    p_m = data.isnull().mean()
    
    # Calculate the proportion of complete cases for each variable
    p_c = data.dropna().shape[0] / data.shape[0]
    
    # Calculate the correlation matrix for all pairs of variables that have complete cases
    R_c = data.dropna().corr()
    
    # Calculate the correlation matrix for all pairs of variables using all observations
    R_all = data.corr()
    
    # Calculate the difference between the two correlation matrices
    R_diff = R_all - R_c
    
    # Calculate the variance of the R_diff matrix
    V_Rdiff = np.var(R_diff, ddof=1)
    
    # Calculate the expected value of V_Rdiff under the null hypothesis that the missing data is MCAR
    E_Rdiff = (1 - p_c) / (1 - p_m).sum()
    
    # Calculate the test statistic
    T = np.trace(R_diff) / np.sqrt(V_Rdiff * E_Rdiff)
    
    # Calculate the degrees of freedom
    df = data.shape[1] * (data.shape[1] - 1) / 2
    
    # Calculate the p-value using a chi-squared distribution with df degrees of freedom and the test statistic T
    p_value = 1 - chi2.cdf(T ** 2, df)
    
    # Create a matrix of missing values that represents the pattern of missingness in the dataset
    missingness_matrix = data.isnull().astype(int)
    
    # Return the missingness matrix and the p-value
    return missingness_matrix, p_value
```

Comment: Cool. What df do you expect as input? And I thought Little's test should return one test with one p-value, not one per column.

Answer (score 0):

Comments suggest using existing packages. Here is an [example](https://rianneschouten.github.io/pyampute/build/html/pyampute.exploration.html#module-pyampute.exploration.mcar_statistical_tests) directly taken from `pyampute`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyampute.exploration.mcar_statistical_tests import MCARTest
data_mcar = pd.read_table("data/missingdata_mcar.csv")
mt = MCARTest(method="little")
print(mt.little_mcar_test(data_mcar))
0.17365464213775494
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import chi2

def little_mcar_test(data, alpha=0.05):
    """
    Performs Little's MCAR (Missing Completely At Random) test on a dataset with missing values.
    """
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    data.columns = ['x' + str(i) for i in range(data.shape[1])]
    data['missing'] = np.sum(data.isnull(), axis=1)
    n = data.shape[0]
    k = data.shape[1] - 1
    df = k * (k - 1) / 2
    chi2_crit = chi2.ppf(1 - alpha, df)
    chi2_val = ((n - 1 - (k - 1) / 2) ** 2) / (k - 1) / ((n - k) * np.mean(data['missing']))
    p_val = 1 - chi2.cdf(chi2_val, df)
    if chi2_val > chi2_crit:
        print(
            'Reject null hypothesis: Data is not MCAR (p-value={:.4f}, chi-square={:.4f})'.format(p_val, chi2_val)
        )
    else:
        print(
            'Do not reject null hypothesis: Data is MCAR (p-value={:.4f}, chi-square={:.4f})'.format(p_val, chi2_val)
        )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).